# setting badge when Firebase Cloud Message is received in Ionic App

Tags: java, android, ionic2, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm having a hard time getting responses to my questions lately and I'm not why. If I am not asking right, can someone please let me know so I can adjust?

I am building an app with Ionic but having issues sending badge numbers for Android via FCM. I can't find anything in the Firebase Docs. How do I set the badge count when a message is received?

Here is my thought process but I don't know how to get it to work:

1. when the message is received, use the [ionic native badge plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/badge/) to set it
2. send the badge count using FCM payload

NOTE: I am using NodeJS implementation for Firebase

**What I've tried**

I am using the **cordova-plugin-fcm** plugin and the Android ShortcutBadger to set the badge, but I am unable to set the badge when the message is received. I was only able to set it when the app is already open by calling the shortcutbadger function in the MyFirebaseMessagingService java class (of the cordova-plugin-fcm). Below is the code I am using in my FCMPluginActivity java class:

```
// more imports here    
import me.leolin.shortcutbadger.ShortcutBadger;

public class FCMPluginActivity extends Activity {
    private static String TAG = "FCMPlugin";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "==> FCMPluginActivity onCreate");

        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "==> USER TAPPED NOTFICATION");
            data.put("wasTapped", true);
            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);
                Log.d(TAG, "\tKey: " + key + " Value: " + value);
                data.put(key, value);
            }
        }

        FCMPlugin.sendPushPayload(data);
        ShortcutBadger.applyCount(FCMPluginActivity.this, 8);
        finish();

        forceMainActivityReload();
    }
```

I am importing ShortcutBadger and using it in the onCreate method. The idea is to set the badger when the notification is received; however, this is not working.

Your thoughts and comments are very much appreciated

Comment: You are not asking a clear question here. Have you tried this approach. It should work. But FYI, using Firebase plugin, you can also set the badge. No need for ionic's native badge plugin: https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

Comment: @Ari. The problem I have with using the cordova-plugin-firebase is that it wouldn't set the badge when the message is received (if the app is completely closed). It sets it after the app is opened.

Comment: @Ari I have updated my question to include what I have tried and what's not working. any thoughts? much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Set the badge field when you send the notification. The documentation specifies this for ios and based on my test it works, but with some delay. I would also try it for Android, but it may not be possible:

Search for 'badge' here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: Thanks @Ari but my problem is getting badging to work on Android. Any idea on how I can achieve this? That is why I am trying to edit the FCM plugin directly.

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Ari. I really appreciate you helpping me out. I found that post already and it might just be because its old but it didn't work for me. I couldn't find any zzE function to override as he suggested looking for. However, I *finally* have figured out a solution that works and will be posting the solution in detail, in case it saves others time in the future :)

Comment: Would love to see the solution!